# Selenium: send_keys() doesn't work on headless Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, headless-browser

I am working with headless Firefox, which is on headless Ubuntu at digitalocean.
Below is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver =  webdriver.Firefox()
main_window = driver.current_window_handle

driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')


driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
print driver.title

driver.get("http://www.bing.com")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
print driver.title

for i in range(0,3):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
    driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
    print driver.title
```

Result is:

> Google
>   Bing
>   Bing
>   Bing
>   Bing

which means send_keys(), which makes tabs and switch between tabs, didn't work at all. There was no runtime error.
The same code can switch between tabs on my local computer, which has physical keyboard and monitor.

I suspect that headless Ubuntu or Firefox made send_keys didn't work.
Any help? Thanks! I read a lot on google, but didn't help.

---------------------------EDIT---------------------------

My headless firefox's version is 45.0.1. Interestingly, I ran same code with firefox 45.0.1 on my Mac, and it worked perfectly. I use firefox45.0.1 on both headless linux and Mac

Comment: What Version of firefox are you using? We had to roll back to a previous version because selenium's web driver doesn't fully support the newest one.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34890679/3579910) suggests firefox does not support what you want to do -> it opens windows instead of tabs. You can use separate windows or switch browsers.

Comment: I am in a situation that I'd better switch between tabs rather than windows.

Comment: My headless firefox's version is 45.0.1. Interestingly, I ran same code with firefox 45.0.1 on my Mac, and it worked perfectly. I use firefox45.0.1 on both headless linux and Mac.

Comment: We encountered issues with FF45 and for our purposes had to rollback and install FF44. You're having a different issue though, so I'm not sure if that will help.

Comment: Thank you. To be more specific, mine is firefox-mozilla-build_45.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64. But I don't know difference between firefox-mozilla-build and just firefox.

Comment: I found that send_keys() works, but I thought it doesn't because focus on the newly made tab was not proper and driver.get() was executed on one same tab.