# How to close auto opened tabs in selenium before opening the next new tab?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Upon collecting various links in a page, i click on those and collect it into a soup. Now the issue is, links are opened in a new tab. I want to close the tab before the code opens the next link in a new tab. Below is the code snippet. Please help me to close each tab after collecting the soup.

I use python 3.7 selenium chromedriver

```py
# collecting results from page 1 only.
candidate_name = []
candidate_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-tn-element='resume-result-link[]']")
for candidates in candidate_links:
    candidate_name.append(candidates.text)
    candidates.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.getText()

    candidates.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'w')
    #write it to a text file
    for i in candidate_name:
        path = r'c:/users/user/desktop/resumes1/'+ i
        with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(text)

time.sleep(5)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do you not need to switch to the new tab to collect the soup?

Comment: No i dont want to switch between tabs. After collecting soup, i wan to close the tab.

Comment: Does that mean that, when you click the link, some containers in the main page (which you want to scrape) gets updated asynchronously, while at the same time, a new tab opens (sort of like some adverts telling you to install some software for your machine's performance boost) and that is the tab that you want to close?

Comment: The above code closes all tabs once the loop is finished.

Comment: I think your case is relevant to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455355/how-to-switch-to-another-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java#34890679. Check UPDATE (11/16/2016) posted by pcalkins. The `Ctrl-W` that you're trying to do is broken. In any case, driver.close() will close the active tab.

Comment: I dont want to scrape any from the main page. The main page is static and no update happens there. The webpage simply opens the links in new tabs. Around 60 tabs are open and the above code closes all tabs once the loop is finished. So when first link is clicked, it opens a new tab, collects soup and leaves it open. Then second link is clicked, opens in new tab, collects soup and leaves it open...so with all links.

Comment: Will try the mentioned link @kerwei.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code worked for me as below. Closed the tabs before opening the next one.

```py
# switch to the tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

# do whatever in the tab
time.sleep(5)

# close the tab
driver.close()

#switch back to the main window again
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```